# how to determine libraries involved in segfault

Tags: perl, gdb, segmentation-fault, nagios

I have nagios 3.2.3 running on CentOS 5.7, and something is causing it to segfault. recently many servers were added to the configuration so its hard to tell what additional directive is triggering the problem.

However the nagios 3.2.3 package comes from rpmforge and many of the existing perl libs are likely to be CentOS base/updates repos, so I am expecting that some conflicting library is causing this..

Running the nagios server binary under strace results in the following segfault;

```
open("/usr/bin/p1.pl", O_RDONLY)        = 4
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fffefee6da0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=31878, ...}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/usr/bin/nagios"..., 4095) = 15
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
```

so some things that I have tried;

1. the kernel is up to date, and the server has been rebooted. yum -y
2. update has been run, and server rebooted /usr/bin/nagios -v
3. /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg passes the pre-flight check

cant disable the embedded perl without recompiling, which is a massive annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

> `--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---`

That means some code dereferenced a NULL pointer.

Run `/usr/bin/nagios` under GDB, and use `where` command to find out *which* code did this.